# How to read IEnumerable List values one by one in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms, ienumerable, picker

I need to read a List that has two properties, one is an ID int, the other is string.
After I get the values into the list I don't know how to break them down to the the IDs and name string one by one.

This is what I've got:

```
private async void UpdatePisterosLocal(List<Pisteros> PisterosLista)
        {
            try
            {
                PisterosDBController pistDB = new PisterosDBController();
                Pisteros_Local pistLocal = new Pisteros_Local();

                //this is my code trying to read the list PisterosLista
                foreach (string element in PisterosLista)
                {
                    pistLocal.IDPistero = //don't know what to write here
                    pistLocal.PisteroN = //and here
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just store the results of `GetTasksAsync();` once and process it twice, instead of calling it twice?

Comment: I believe you didn't understand my question. I need to take the data and store it in another database, so to do that I need to go throught it with a cycle, either for the list or the picker

Comment: You could create a list property to store the data you get from the url. And then do the change with the list. It only needs to use the `GetTasksAsync` once.

Comment: The question is slightly confusing, could you possibly rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I finally did it

```
foreach (var item in PisterosLista)
        {
            var DatosRegistro = new T_Pisteros
            {
                PisteroID = item.PisteroID,
                PisteroN = item.PisteroN
            };
            var num = db.Insert(DatosRegistro); //insert into new DB
        }
```